# condicionales en mustache

Tags: template

Tengo que declarar la siguiente condición en una plantilla mustache.

Si "type" == "slider", entonces imprimes la variable "prueba".

He hecho lo siguiente:

```
{{#type}}
{{#slider}}
{{{prueba}}}
{{/slider}}
{{/type}}
```

"prueba" es el string que quiero imprimir y si lo pongo solo, funciona, pero al poner el condicional no sale nada. 
¿Alguien sabe donde está el error de sintaxis?

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que estas en Javascript, lo que si me funciona siempre es que la variable a comparar para mostrar/ocultar sea un booleano.
Create una variable con el resultado de la comparación

```
model.isSlider = type == "slider";
```

Y luego utilízala en el template

```
{{#isSlider}}
Es Slider
{{/isSlider}}
```

Espero q te sirva